# jquery - disable href inside a html frame from the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-frames

I have set of html elements selected by javascript function and I want to pass this to jquery and disable all the html links in this list.Please let me know , how to achieve this.

```
var links = window.frames[1].document.getElementsByTagName("a");
```

If it is normal single html page then I can select the links using the below jquery function and disable links. As I have html frames associated with this, jquery is not able to select the frame element.

So I have selected it using javascript thats is "links".

```
$("a").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                    <li>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id ="test" href="/Frame1.html" target="detail"><i class="demo-icon icon-chart-line fa-fw"></i> Status<span class="demo-icon icon-right-open-1"></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/Frame2.html" target="detail"><i class="demo-icon icon-flow-tree fa-fw"></i> Setup<span class="demo-icon icon-right-open-1"></span></a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <div id="navfooter">

                    <div id="copyright-loader">
                        <!--<i class="demo-icon icon-spin6 animate-spin" style='font-size:6em; color:#31bbd6;'></i> <br><br>-->
                        <img alt="logo" class="img-responsive" src="../images/logo.jpg" />
                    </div>

                    <br clear='all' /> <br />

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Does the frame share the same domain as the page ? It can be a "security" issue.

Comment: What do you mean by `html frame`?

Comment: You could replace the `href` value with `#`. But by doing that you are no longer able to enable them.

Comment: Hi Lucas , the problem is selecting the elements to disable ..disable is working fine if I do e.preventDefault .

Answer (score 1):

Add a css style pointer-event:none to anchor tag.

document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.pointerEvents = "none";

Test with chrome and firefox it work fine. But in IE it will not work

Or remove href attribute from anchor tag

document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].removeAttribute("href");

Comment: remove attribute is fine .but again i want to add the same href..how to do this?